# Terraform local-exec command with complex variables

Tags: terraform

I'd need to iterate through a list of variables in local-exec provider. Is that possible?

variables.tf:

```
variable "items" {
  default = []
}
```

main.tf:

```
resource "null_resource" "loop_list" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    interpreter = ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
    command = <<EOF
      for i in ${join(' ', var.items)}
        print $i
      done
EOF
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this? :)

Comment: I'm just trying to see it in action. I wouldn't think this "pseudocode" could work well on the first try :)

Comment: Ok, then: I would probably create a local variable with join and whatever you wanted to achieve. Second step would be to use templatefile to swap the variable you specify in the script with the value of the local variable. The last step would be to run the script instead of providing it with heredoc syntax. But there are sure multiple possible approaches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use [environment](https://www.terraform.io/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec#environment). Something like this:

```
variable "items" {
  default = ["item1", "item2"]
}

resource "null_resource" "loop_list" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command     = "for item in $ITEMS; do echo $item >> test-file; done"
    environment = { ITEMS = join(" ", var.items) }
  }
}
```

Where `terraform apply` and `cat test-file` yields:

```
item1
item2
```